# is it possible to let user change TextView text from static table

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

So I have a static Tablelayout with multiple TableRows and inside I have 2 cell  as TextView .

My Issue is that I want to let the user change the text of every one of the `TextView` ,and also this one i succeeded , **my problem** is that I want to keep the value from the next time user enter to the activity or the app,in other words let the user change the `android:text=""` value forever.

Comment: If you want to persist data in the TextViews use SharedPreferences or a database.

Comment: You need to write the data to disk somewhere (SharedPreference, database, file, etc).  Then when your app is launched read in that data and call setText on each view changed.  There is no way to change the original xml.

Comment: @KNeerajLal thank you for the quick answer i get the direction